# Disable all MapView gestures and add an OnClickListener to the MapView

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to have a MapView that with all the gestures disabled. It's basically just for a little view in a fragment that when you press on it, it goes to a LocationPickerFragment. I don't think I'm doing it in the right way or neither the recommended way (as isn't working), but maybe you could give me a clue? I want to disable all the google maps stuff and add to the MapView an OnClickListener or other listener that allow me to execute some code when the user presses on the MapView.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To learn how to disable gesture, you can read [this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html)

For example, To disable rotate gestures, you do

```
myMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false); // Care to use getUiSettings(), not getUiSetting()
```

OnClickListerner can be read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener.html). It is called when the user makes a tap gesture on the map, but only if none of the overlays of the map handled the gesture.

```
onMapClick(LatLng point)
```

Comment: I knew how to disable the gestures, the OnMapClickListener did the magic. Cheers.

Comment: Not sure it matters, considering it's a decade later, but both links are broken.

Answer (score 2):

There is `googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);` to disable all gestures.